# Exclude Rows in PySpark Containing String Values

Tags: python, pyspark

I have a PySpark dataframe that looks like this:

```
+----+------+-----+
|name|amount| item|
+----+------+-----+
| Bob|  5.62|juice|
| Sue|  0.85| milk|
| Joe|  1.04| eggs|
+----+------+-----+
```

I would like to drop the rows whose value in the `item` column contains either `milk` or `eggs.` Here's what I have:

`df = df.filter(~df.item.isin(['milk','eggs'])`

However, this is not working--when I look at the df.show(), the offending rows are still present.

Comment: remove `[]`. try this `df.filter(~df.item.isin('milk', 'eggs'))`

Comment: Do you have try and except clause to mask the errors? Because if you run the piece of code that you've mentioned above, you're gonna get an error for not closing the parenthesis of filter.

Comment: u r missing the last bracket in ur code, do `df.filter(~df.item.isin(['milk','eggs']))`

Comment: Assuming your parentheses are closed, there are no other errors in your code. Is there anything you're not showing us?

Comment: Just make sure there are any leading or trailing spaces for the values in the item column by using trim() on the column and apply filter, else your code looks fine.